# Full text search - containstable - rank 0

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, containstable

Using SQL Server 2016.

I have a table in a database that contains products that I search through "keywords" with Full Text Search.  Our client has asked that we remove the single character "n" from the stop list to allow for searching on terms like "fish n chips" (not a real example).

However, after altering the stop list and rebuilding the index I am seeing unexpected results, in particular a rank of zero:

```
SELECT * FROM  CONTAINSTABLE (dbo.Products, Keywords, ' "no*"')
SELECT * FROM  CONTAINSTABLE (dbo.Products, Keywords, ' "n*"')
```

Gives me results of:

[image]

As you can see I am getting a rank of 0 for all results.  I have tried this with other characters and I get `RANK` as expected.  I have checked the stop lists via:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_stoplists
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_stopwords 
WHERE stoplist_id = 5 AND language_id = 1033
```

In general I can see no reason for having a rank of 0 returned.  What has confused me more is that I have a second database on the same server using the same indexing and stop list, and its not an issue.

I have been looking into this and seen people having this issue around `FREETEXTTABLE` however the issue here is not down to lack of data.

If anyone has any idea on things I can check to help track this down it would be gratefully received.